# Upper and lower Riemann sum of Partitions depending on $n$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, riemann-integration

I am currently self studying Riemann integrability and got to a part that states that if partitions P and Q are such that Q is a refinement of P then $$L (f,P) \leq U (f,Q) \leq U (f,Q) \leq U (f,P)$$ 
I fully understand the proof. It is based on the fact that every point of P is in Q.

My thought is this: Suppose I have a partition dependent on n, say:
$$P_n:=\{x_0,x_{1,n},x_{2,n},...,x_{p,n}\}$$
Like for example,
$$P_n:=\{0,\frac{1}{n},\frac{2}{n},...,1\}$$
Will I also have that 
 $$L (f,P_n) \leq U (f,P_{n+1}) \leq U (f,P_{n+1}) \leq U (f,P_n)?$$ 
I am stuck on how to approach this, or even get a counter example.

If it is false, should there be any condition to be put on $f$, say continuity or something else?

Comment: I believe you mea $L \leq L \leq U \leq U.$ If you have $P_n$ is a subfamily of $P_{n+1}$ then it's a corollary of what you have already.

Comment: @WillM. The problem is that $P_{n+1}$ is not necessarily a refinement of $P_n$

Comment: I am silly, I forgot the following result before: if $P$ and $Q$ are _any_ partitions, then $L(f, P) \leq U(f, Q).$ (Use what you have with a common refinement.)